# Is there a way in Visual Studio to specify what a template class (new class) is going to look like?

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2005

I'm a long time Eclipse user trying to learn to Visual Studio.  I know that Eclipse had Code Templates that would allow you to build classes with certain comments and formatting already added for a class.

For example:

- Auto placing the copyright for the code at the top of the file
- Who created the file
- Predefined Comments,
- etc...

Does Visual Studio 2005 have any functionality like this?

Answer (score 1):

It depends. Visual Studio has a built-in [code snippets manager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wy5tazc9%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) that lets you do things like this to at least a degree (i.e., if you insert a code snippet, it'll be formatted as the snippet specifies, but if you write the same code manually, it won't). Also note that there are limitations on the languages with which you can use code snippets.

Outside of that, most of the major add-ins for VS (e.g., [Visual Assist-X](http://www.wholetomato.com/)) provide their own ability to store and insert bits of code, formatted as you specify. Most of these provide at least some features missing from the built-in snippets manager such as working with other languages or being easier to access (along with quite a few other things -- IMO, VS borders on completely unusable without VA-X).

Comment: Yeah it looks to me like there are code snippets for every language but C++ in VS2005.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend looking at item and project templates in Visual Studio, which sound like what you're looking for. But, in your particular case (C++ development), it doesn't look like this is available to you.

The following MSDN article refers to VS templates, and mentions that for Visual C++ projects, that the template architecture isn't supported. Instead, there's information on creating custom wizards for your project and classes, which may give you the flexibility that you need. Sounds like it'll do what you want it to do, but it's much more work than it would be if you could use an item template for including basic comment structure for a default class file.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6db0hwky%28VS.80%29.aspx